# RegExp in JavaScript with Case Sensitive Modifier

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In the following code, I have used RegExp to check `E` with Case Sensitive Modifier `i` in the string `The best things in life are free`. But it is returning `true` even if there is no uppercase `E` in the string.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var patt1=new RegExp("E","i");

document.write(patt1.test("The best things in life are free"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The *i* stands for “case insensitive”.

Comment: @Gumbo Thats what the problem is. RegExp should return `false` because there is no uppercase `E` in the string `The best things in life are free`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are case sensitive *by default* just get rid of the `i` flag. The `i` flag stands for **ignore** case.

note it's typically easier to write regular expressions as:

```
/E/.test(inputstring)
```

but if you're *just* testing for the presence of a fixed string it's better to not use a regex at all

```
containsChar = (inputstring.indexOf('E') > -1);
```

You can find out more about [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on [mozilla's javascript reference site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/)